# Save data through the controller after an event has been fired in laravel

Tags: laravel, events, listener

I'm allowing a user to upload a post which includes an image and some related information as well as select the promotion fee[bronze,silver or gold].In my **/post** controller i'm validating the request and then sending a request to another API[third party api for performing  payments].The API takes the user phone number and the promotion fee selected and does the payment transaction.So i made the **Transaction** model[used to save details concerning the completed transaction]to dispatch a **created** event since i  want to save the other post related information only if the payment is successful.

I've tried to create the listener for the **TransactionCreatedEvent** but i can't find a way to pass the post related data into the listener in order to save them. I also tried to use the closure by calling the listen method on the Event Facade inside the post controller to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Mh, i'm not quite sure if i undestood you question correctly, but in you case, you could either relate the Transaction with the post, or  pass the Transaction and the Post Model to any event or to a job, and then do whatever you want with the data in the event handler or job